# XGBoost Walk forward validation feature_names mismatch

Tags: python, time-series, xgboost, stock

I am trying to predict the stock trend where 1 is the stock increases and 0 is the stock decreases on that particular day. My input features are close price, volume, current day trend and my output is the trend the next day. When applying walk forward validation I encounter an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

<ipython-input-309-dbcd60f21dc7> in validate(data, perc)
     11         test_x, test_y = test[i, :-1], test[i, -1]
     12 
---> 13         pred = xgb_predict(history, test_x[0])
     14         predictions.append(test[i])
     15 

<ipython-input-295-f5fe87fd7777> in xgb_predict(train, val)
      6 
      7     val = np.array(val).reshape(1, -1)
----> 8     pred = model.predict(val)
      9     return pred[0]
     10 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in predict(self, data, output_margin, ntree_limit, validate_features, base_margin)
    968         if ntree_limit is None:
    969             ntree_limit = getattr(self, "best_ntree_limit", 0)
--> 970         class_probs = self.get_booster().predict(
    971             test_dmatrix,
    972             output_margin=output_margin,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in predict(self, data, output_margin, ntree_limit, pred_leaf, pred_contribs, approx_contribs, pred_interactions, validate_features, training)
   1483 
   1484         if validate_features:
-> 1485             self._validate_features(data)
   1486 
   1487         length = c_bst_ulong()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in _validate_features(self, data)
   2058                             ', '.join(str(s) for s in my_missing))
   2059 
-> 2060                 raise ValueError(msg.format(self.feature_names,
   2061                                             data.feature_names))
   2062 

ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2'] ['f0']
expected f2, f1 in input data
```

My code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def validate(data, perc):
    predictions = []
    
    train, test = train_test_split(data, perc)
    
    history = [x for x in train]
    
    for i in range (len(test)):
        test_x, test_y = test[i, :-1], test[i, -1]
        
        pred = xgb_predict(history, test_x[0])
        predictions.append(test[i])
        
    error = mean_squared_error(test[:, -1], predictions, squared=False)
    
    return error, test[:, -1], predictions 

%%time 

rmse, y, pred = validate(data, 0.2)

print(rsme)
```

Should I be trying to find accuracy instead of rsme or is it something to do with my columns. I have included [a sample of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7kkl.png). Thank you very much for the help :)